# Разница между parallel() and parallelStream()?

Tags: java

Какая разница между parallel() and parallelStream()? Что-то ни дока ни инфа в инете пока не помогают. Если это важно, то для примера возьмем обычный arraylist c 100 000 элементов.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603186/why-does-collection-parallelstream-exist-when-stream-parallel-does-the-sa

Comment: @Suvitruf совсем непонятно, одна вода без четких аргументов. Ну не считая пары мест))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разницы между методами `parallelStream()` и `stream().parallel()`, вызванными для коллекций нет. Единственное, что делается в каждом случае - поток помечается флагом, что он может выполняться в несколько потоков. А вот будет он выполняться в несколько потоков (и насколько много их может быть) или нет - зависит от реализации *сплитератора*, на основании которого поток создаётся.

Более того, можно снять этот флаг, вызвав у потока метод `sequential()`, и тогда такой поток не будет распараллелен.

Если для потока вызвать несколько раз подряд методы `parallel()` или `sequential()` то эффект будет от того вызова, который был последним (соответственно, какое значение флага осталось после последнего вызова).

Answer (score 0):

Есть одно предположение:

`Collection.parallelStream()` вы можете вызвать только на коллекции, т.е. сразу распараллелить задачу.

`В случае Stream.parallel()` вы можете выполнить какие-либо действия со стримом в однопоточном режиме и после распараллелить.

Так же как и в случае `Collection.foreach()` и `Stream.foreach()`

Вы либо сразу на коллекции вызываете `foreach()` либо сначла выполняете нужные вам действия и потом вызываете `foreach()`

Comment: Но это всего лишь предположение((